# can not change hostname

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, configuration, hostname

I want to change the hostname of a Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I did:

```
hostnamectl --set-hostname newname --static
changed /etc/hostname file to newname
changed /etc/hosts file to newname
rm -f /etc/machine-id
dbus-uuidgen --ensure=/etc/machine-id
dbus-uuidgen --ensure
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Finally I did a reboot. But after reboot there is still the old hostname. The file /etc/hostname has been changed to the old hostname.

How to permanently change the hostname?

Comment: hi. did you try "hostname newname" as root?

Comment: yes, of course all commands as root

Comment: Have the same problem here, done all that and after reboot well, we were taken for a ride, because all our work wen't done the drain. Do have half an answer for you thought, the /etc/hosts file also get undone, found 23.04 is using a template located at /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl. If you edit that file at least your hosts file will be configured correctly. We'll keep informing.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally I had to change the file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

There is a setting `preserve_hostname: false`

I had to change that from false to true.
After rebbot hostname had changed.

Comment: Thank you!  Wasted hours trying to change hostname on 22.04 due to this.